# Glassfish error in GZIP

Tags: jakarta-ee, gzip, glassfish-3

I get the following error log in my Glassfish 3.0.1 server very often. It seems Glassfish server returns blank page to the user when it encounters this error. How can I solve this issue?

(I face this issue after I enabled HTTP GZIP compression in the server)

```
*Timestamp

Jul 4, 2011 06:15:43.174
Log Level

SEVERE
Logger

javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl
Name-Value Pairs

{_ThreadName=Thread-1, _ThreadID=24}
Record Number

2557
Message ID

org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException
Complete Message

java.io.IOException: write beyond end of stream at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:425) at com.sun.grizzly.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:433) at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:373) at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:336) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.close(CoyoteOutputStream.java:188) at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.implCloseChannel(Channels.java:286) at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.close(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:97) at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:290) at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:119) at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:310) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215) at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215) at com.myproject.filter.UtfFilter.doFilter(UtfFilter.java:123) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97) at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693) at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954) at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102) at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88) at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76) at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53) at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57) at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330) at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) Caused by: java.io.IOException: write beyond end of stream at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:104) at java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream.write(GZIPOutputStream.java:72) at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.filters.GzipOutputFilter.doWrite(GzipOutputFilter.java:125) at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:640) at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.Response.doWrite(Response.java:676) at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:420) ... 41 more*
```